# How can I add or remove an option from the middle of the multi-value react-select input?

Tags: react-select

react-select allows to add or remove an option from the end (right) of the multi-value select component.

Is there a way of adding or removing an option by placing the cursor in the middle or anywhere in between of the multi-value input ?

https://react-select.com/home